# Find a $4$th degree polynomial which has as roots the inverses of the roots of the polynomial $f= X^4 - 5X^3 + 3X^2 - X + 1$.

Tags: polynomials

Consider the polynomial

$$f = X^4 - 5 X^3 + 3 X^2 - X + 1$$

which has the roots $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4 \in \mathbb{C}$. I have to find a 
$4$th degree polynomial $g \in \mathbb{C}[X]$ which has the roots $\dfrac{1}{x_1}, \dfrac{1}{x_2}, \dfrac{1}{x_3}, \dfrac{1}{x_4}$. I've done this type of problem before, but only in circumstances where it was very easy to factor the initial polynomial and I could very quickly find the roots $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ and then find their inverses. But I see no clear way of factoring $f$ in this particular problem.

Comment: Hint: which roots does the function $f(1/x)$ have?

Comment: Hint: $ X \rightarrow \frac{1}{x}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to factor $f(X)$ to answer this question.

If $X^4-5X^3+3X^2-X+1=0$, then $X\ne0$, so we can divide by $X^4 $ to get

$1-\dfrac5X+\dfrac3{X^2}-\dfrac1{X^3}+\dfrac1{X^4}=0$,

so $g\left(\dfrac1X\right)=0,$ where $g(x)=x^4-x^3+3x^2-5x+1$.